# Trace hierarchical tree for JSON array

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl, associative-array

I just can't understand why I get undefined index for 'post' in the foreach. Here's the function I use to authenticate to the API via cURL, grab the JSON, cache it and extrapolate with the foreach the info I need:

```
<?php
// JSON URL which should be requested
$json_url = 'https://api.del.icio.us/v1/posts/recent';

$username = 'USERNAME';  // authentication
$password = 'PASSWORD';  // authentication

// Initializing curl
$ch = curl_init( $json_url );

// Configuring curl options
$options = array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_USERPWD => $username . ":" . $password   // authentication
);

// Setting curl options
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );



$cache_delicious = '/MY_DIR/'.sha1($json_url).'.json';

    if(file_exists($cache_delicious) && filemtime($cache_delicious) > time() - 1000){
        // if a cache file newer than 1000 seconds exist, use it
        $data_delicious = file_get_contents($cache_delicious);
    } else {

        $delicious_result = simplexml_load_string(curl_exec($ch));
        $data_delicious = json_encode($delicious_result);
        file_put_contents($cache_delicious, $data_delicious);
    }

    $obj = $data_delicious;

foreach (array_slice(json_decode($data_delicious, true), 0, 5) as $obj) {
    $delicious_title = str_replace('"', '\'', $obj['post']['@attributes']['description']);
    $delicious_url = htmlentities($obj['post']['@attributes']['href'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
    $output = "<li><a rel=\"external nofollow\" title=\"$delicious_title\" href=\"$delicious_url\">$delicious_title</a></li>";
    echo $output;
}
?>
```

And here's the JSON (if I do a `print_r($data_delicious);` ):

```
{
   "@attributes":{
      "tag":"",
      "user":"myusername"
   },
   "post":[
      {
         "@attributes":{
            "description":"MY FEED TITLE",
            "extended":"",
            "hash":"d00d03acd6e01e9c2e899184eab35273",
            "href":"http:\/\/myurl.com\/",
            "private":"no",
            "shared":"yes",
            "tag":"",
            "time":"2013-06-13T10:30:08Z"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To access `json_decode`d objects as an array you have set the second parameter to json_decode to true, otherwise it creates objects instead of associative arrays.

```
$data_delicious = json_encode($delicious_result, true);
```

Comment: I modified that line but I still get "undefined index" for 'post' in the foreach: `$obj['post']['@attributes']['description']` and `$obj['post']['@attributes']['href']`.

Comment: Even if I remove 'post' and I leave just `$obj['@attributes']['description']` and `$obj['@attributes']['href']` I get undefined index for "@attributes". :(

Comment: try `$obj["post"][0]["@attributes"]["description"]` post is an array of objects

Comment: Nope :( Still "FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: post"